# Scanner.nextInt() throwing InputMismatchException when reading an integer

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

I'm having a problem with my code that seems like it should be running perfectly.

```
public void inputFile() {
    Scanner reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new Scanner( new File ("parts.dat"));
        reader.useDelimiter("\\,|\\n");
        while(reader.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(reader.next());
            System.out.println(reader.next());
            System.out.println(reader.nextDouble());
            System.out.println(reader.nextInt()); //InputMismatchException
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
    }   
    finally {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following output:

```
137B245
1/4" bolt
0.59
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at lab02d.inputFile(lab02d.java:25)
    at lab02d.main(lab02d.java:11)
```

parts.dat contains:

```
137B245,1/4" bolt,.59,12
137N245,1/4" nut,.29,12
137B246,1/2" bolt,.79,12
137N246,1/2" nut,.39,25
139S128,1/8" wood screw,.19,8
139S129,1/4" wood screw,.22,4
139S130,1/2" wood screw,.35,16
145W321,1/8" washer,.12,5
145W322,1/4" washer,.14,6
145W323,1/2" washer,.18,9
```

I have tried several things to try to get this code to work. I have tried using Integer.parseInt(reader.next()), but that just throws another exception. I've also tried changing the text file encoding, but that didn't fix anything either.

Comment: Can you put `e.printStackTrace()` in the `catch` block and post that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain your file has additional white space at the end of those lines, preventing the scanner from parsing what looks like a reasonable int.  Like a carriage return.  Adjust your delimiter to something like below, and try again:

```
reader.useDelimiter("[\\,\\n\\r]+");
```